# How to serve from Cloudflare cache without requesting the Cloudflare Worker?

Tags: caching, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I have a Cloudflare Worker, whose responses can be cached for a long time. I know I can use Cache API inside the worker, but I want the request to never reach the worker at all, if Cache TTL is not reached.

There will be more than 10 million requests to this url, and I don't see the point paying for a Worker, that most of the time will just fetch a response from the Cache API.

I know a workaround - just host the worker code on a server, and use Page Rules, to cache everything from this origin. But I'm wondering if I could use Worker as origin, and somehow make Page Rules work with it. Just setting a Page Rule to cache everythig and cache TTL setting to 1 month still routes all requests to the Worker and doesn't cache anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this.

It's important to understand that this is really a pricing question, not a technical question. Cloudflare has chosen to price Workers based on the traffic level of a site that is served using Workers. This pricing decision isn't necessarily based on Cloudflare's costs, and Cloudflare's costs wouldn't necessarily be lower if your Worker runs less often (since the cost of deployment would not change, and the cost of executing a worker is quite low), so it doesn't necessarily make sense for Cloudflare to offer a discount for Worker-based sites that manage to serve most responses from cache.

With that said, Cloudflare could very well decide to offer this discount in the future for competitive or other reasons. But, at this time, there are no plans for this.

There's a longer explanation on the Cloudflare forums: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cache-in-front-of-worker/171258/8